# Socket connection without Port specification

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to connect with an instrument: https://download.tek.com/manual/071163106web_0.pdf

The manual does not provide any port nor the instrument interface. It finds the IP address and domain via DHCP, but there is no port.

I am connecting with socket via python, however AF_INET demands port and when I give any port I receive: `connection refused`. I can also ping the instrument, so it means that at least that the instrument is alive.

Here is my minimum working example:

```py
import socket

socket_obj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

socket_obj.settimeout(1)

socket_obj.connect(("192.168.2.3", 4000))
```

which yields:

```
$ ...
$ socket_obj.connect((192.168.2.3, 4000))
$ ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I tried several ports, none of them work. I also tried several timeouts.

My question: is there a way to connect without providing the port?

Comment: Looks like your AFG uses a protocol call VXI-11, you’ll likely have to use a library or software that talks the vxi-11 for you, and it will know what port(s) to connect on.

Comment: The VXI-11 protocol is complicated. [Here is a paper](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/IPAC10/papers/wepeb004.pdf) describing a python implementation. It's an old paper so you may have to track down where the code is today.